# Caret is moving backwards when a comma is added

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, caret, cursor-position

I'm using Ionic (and Angular). I have a directive which changes the value of an input after transforming it using [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe). The values are numeric only.

The problem is that when a comma is added to the number (for example: when the user changes the value from 100 to 1,000) the cursor is moving backward one place.
It looks like it doesn't care that a comma was added.

My code:

```
   let decimalPipe = new DecimalPipe(window.navigator.language);
   val = decimalPipe.transform(val, this.numberDecimal());


  this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(val);
  this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input'), 'value', val);

  this.model.viewToModelUpdate(val);
```

The `model` is of type [NgControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgControl#valueAccessor) and the `renderer` is of type [Renderer](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was for Android devices only. I didn't find a solution so I wrote a workaround that changes the caret's position after a timeout  of 0 milliseconds.

```
// before the change 
let inputElem = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
let caretPos = inputElem.selectionStart;
let numOfCommas = (value.match(/,/g) || []).length;
...

//after the change
 let newNumOfCommas = (val.match(/,/g) || []).length;
 if (newNumOfCommas != numOfCommas)
 {
     setTimeout(() =>
     {
        let pos = newNumOfCommas > numOfCommas ? caretPos+1 : caretPos - 1;
        inputElem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
     }, 0);
 }
```